# call python cloud endpoint api from android app

Tags: android, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have successfully created the api in cloud endpoint and deployed it in app engine. Its in python. also I have generated library and have imported in my project.Its in my import

`import com.appspot.corner_fresh.fresh_api.FreshApi;`

How can i access methods in my api. I have methods like `fresh_api.user.insert` and `fresh_api.user.detail`. I could not get any detailed documentation of python endpoint.

I tried this

```
final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

FreshApi.Builder builder = new FreshApi.Builder( transport, jsonFactory, null );
builder.setApplicationName( appName );

FreshApi service = builder.build();

try {
     Json response = service.fresh_api.users.list( ).execute();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sexyfghfd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

but, first I couldn't understand it. Then, what to pass as appName in `builder.setApplicationName( appName );`

also, its not recognising methodName in

`response = service.fresh_api.users.list( ).execute();`
 how to execute api and get response. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, try to use:

```
service.fresh_api().users.list( ).execute();
```

Because fresh_api is not an attribute, but a method. If you use Android Studio, you can press Ctrl + Space and see the list of available method and operations.

For the first question, it may refer to your AppEngine backend application id. But you don't have to set that. The most important is your Client Key for Android, and the Endpoint root URL.

Comment: It worked as  `UsersCollection response = service.users().list().execute();` . Thanx. If you can, help me with this, I am really stuck.. http://bit.ly/1zfFUkN